# i want to transfer data from column to another table column using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i want to transfer data from column to another table column using PHP
for example
table1 has a column "amount" and table 2 column "total".
how can i transfer/copy the value in "amount" to "total"?

sory for my bad english

edit:
i use MySql db

Comment: Use UPDATE sir.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: could you add your code please

Comment: By table do you mean HTML table or SQL table? This question is currently too vague. Please add more details. Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this. here I use userId to select a particular row. you can alter it or not use it according to your requirement.

```
$query = "SELECT amount  FROM table1 WHERE userId='{$id}'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

$sql = "UPDATE table2 SET total='{$result}' WHERE userId='{$id}'";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use below query if you are looking to update MySQL table from PHP.

```
UPDATE `table` SET amount=total;
```

Comment: the column total is in different table

Comment: @ronell: fetch the value first and then update the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$update = mysqli_query('your_connection', 'UPDATE $tablename SET column1 = '$value1', column2 = '$value2' WHERE Condition');
```

For details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html